# Error when trying to configure Postfox via Virtualmin/ Webmin on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to configure Postfix on my server, but see the following error when trying to access the configuration module on Virtualmin:

```
Error while checking current Postfix configuration. Please manually fix Postfix  configuration.

postfix: fatal: chdir(/usr/libexec/postfix): No such file or directory
Manually edit the Postfix configuration file.
```

When I opt to manually edit the Postfix config file, it's empty.

I check the module configuration options and can't see anything out of place (although I don't know what I'm looking for).

After poking around my system, I can see there are main.cf and master.cf in the following locations:

/etc/postfix
/usr/lib/postfix

Should there be two locations for those files?

The location mentioned in the error - /usr/libexec/postfix - doesn't exist. I assume it wants the /usr/lib/postfix location, so how do I tell Virtualmin or the system to look in that location instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem,you must edit your postfix "main.cf" file and change:-

```
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
```

to the following line:

```
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
```

Then restart postfix:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Now your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thanks - I managed to reach that conclusion after I'd posted my question, but SE won't let me answer my own question. Good to see your answer validates what I did, though. Seems the two main.cf files are the original and a symbolic link.

Comment: In Debian postfix is installed in /usr/lib while in red hat it is installed in /usr/libexec,do you have debian?

Comment: Hi, yes (well, I'm running Ubuntu). Postfix seems to be configured by Virtualmin when it is installed, so I assume the issue is perhaps with how Virtualmin configures Postfix. Just 'one of those things', I assume!

Comment: Next time you configure postfix please see path of  daemon_directory of postfix by running command:-postconf -d|grep daemon_directory.